# WebGL does not work after screen lock

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I'm on Xubuntu 14.04 and using chrome 39. When cold starting chrome, webgl works fine, but after the screen locks, webgl stops working, and chrome://gpu shows webgl as not available. I have also tried having a webgl app run when the screen locks, but chrome just freezes up and I have to restart it. Firefox is fine and works perfectly with webgl, and I'm on latest Intel drivers.

Comment: same issue with HD7950 on Lubuntu using i3wm. Happens with fglrx and fglrx-updates driver.

Answer (score 0):

- Install the latest version of the (tested) proprietary driver for your grahics card via Additional drivers in Xubuntu.
- Go to chrome://flags/ with the latest version of Google Chrome.
- In this page, enable Override software rendering list and relaunch Google Chrome.
- Go to chrome://gpu/ and see if WebGL is active.
- Look if your problem is gone or not.

Comment: I have latest intel drivers, via the intel driver installer as it doesn't show up in additional drivers and I already have override software rendering list.

Comment: Please give more details concerning your graphics card and generally your computer.

Comment: It's an integrated gpu with the i5-570m, which I believe is a Intel GMA something. According to lspci it is a "Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)", running on i915 driver